# Animate function: change div width by using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to create an interactive "game" like this:
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2010/11/13/weekinreview/deficits-graphic.html?_r=0

I have a rough draft and it is working nicely with checkboxes, now I want the same behaviour with radio buttons.

But if I click a radio button, then the div shrinks, if I click another one it shrinks again and again. The behavior should be: Click a radio button (shrink 10%) and then click the radion button (shrink 5%) it should grow a little bit. So it should always consider what one has clicked before.

Here is the JavaScript function so far:

```
function animateDiv(val) {
      if (val=="voll") {
       $('#cont').animate({width: '-=10%'}, 500);
      }
      else if (val=="halb") {
        $('#cont').animate({width: '-=5%'}, 500);
      }
      else if (val=="null") {
        $('#cont').animate({width: '-=0%'}, 500);
      }
}
```

Markup:

```
<input id="radio" type="radio" name="kultur" onClick="animateDiv('voll')">Voll
<input id="radio" type="radio" name="kultur" onClick="animateDiv('halb')">Halb
<input id="radio" type="radio" name="kultur" checked="checked" onClick="animateDiv('null')">Null
```

The functionality of the checkboxes you can see here: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/budget

Comment: Post your markup also or provide fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it to remember what the original width was. Maybe, before you animate, check if a .data('originalWidth') has been set. If it has not, set it to what the width is. Then, on each later animate, base it off of that. Something like...

```
function animateDiv(val) {
    var div = $('#cont');
    if(div.data('originalWidth') == undefined)
        div.data('originalWidth', div.width());

    var width = div.data('originalWidth');

    if (val=="voll")
        width *= .9;
    else if (val=="halb") 
        width *= .95;

    $('#cont').animate({width: width}, 500);
}
```

Comment: thats perfekt! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

Keep a global variable in your javascript, say `var globalWidth = $('#cont').width();`

Then change your `animateDiv` function to the following: (the idea is to revert the width to its original and then animate)

```
       function animateDiv(val) {

          $('#cont').css('width',globalWidth);

          if (val=="voll") {
           $('#cont').animate({width: '-=10%'}, 500);
          }
          else if (val=="halb") {
            $('#cont').animate({width: '-=5%'}, 500);
          }
          else if (val=="null") {
            $('#cont').animate({width: '-=0%'}, 500);
          }
        }
```

Comment: While that's a decent solution, maybe have the variable stored inside the element itself, similar to how I did my solution. That way you can reuse the same code for more than one element without having to have one global variable per item

Comment: that works, but it doesnt look very good because the animation jumps to the edge and then shrinks again.